# what font and style is used in \paragraph{} in conjunction with classicthesis and arsclassica?

Tags: fonts, classicthesis

Currently, I'm writing my BSc. thesis and I'm quite close to madness:
I use the

`\paragraph{Nice Pragraph Example}`

command and it mostly does what I expect it to do.

However, it uses a different font for the paragraph heading which is all lowercase.

I nailed it down to the `arsclassica` package and the `lmodern` fonts not being happy together:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
nochapters, % Turn off chapters since this is an article        
]{classicthesis} % The layout is based on the Classic Thesis style
\usepackage{arsclassica} % Modifies the Classic Thesis package
\usepackage{lmodern}    %this option together with the arsclassica package breaks the \paragraph command
%when lmodern is used in conjunction with arsclassica, ther paragraph headings become all lowercase

\begin{document}
hallo, das ist ein Test
\paragraph{Nice ParagraphTitle ABC abc} So soll das sein.
%without lmodern: NICE PARAGRAPHTITLE ABC ABC
%with    lmodern: nice paragraphtitle abc abc

\end{document}
```

When compiling this example I found, that `\usepackage{classicthesis}` converts the paragraph heading to CAPS somehow.

The option `\usepackage{arsclassica}` modifies the used font for the paragraph heading.

Together with the option `\usepackage{lmodern}` it breaks :-(

So do you have a hint for me, how to get this working together.
Maybe the easiest would be to stop `\usepackage{classicthesis}` from converting the paragraph headings into CAPS.

Thanks a lot!

Felix

Comment: The behaviour of `\paragraph{}` depends on which class you use.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not be using a KOMA class, `classicthesis` and `arsclassica` together. Both `classicthesis` and `arsclassica` load `titlesec` which is for the most part incompatible with KOMA classes. The KOMA classes try to accommodate `titlesec`, but there is no guarantee that things work as expected. My editor counts 12 warnings when I compile the small example from the question.

`arsclassica` redefine `\paragraph` and a few other headings to be typeset in bold small caps where text is converted to all lowercase before it is passed to the small caps. Latin Modern has no bold small caps and so you end up with bold lowercase text.

There are several ways you can resolve this. You could, for example, use a font that has bold small caps (Linux Libertine/Libertinus come to mind ...). Or you can tell `arsclassica` to stop making paragraph headings bold and small caps and go for small caps only

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily}
  {\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\theparagraph}}}%
  {0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\begin{document}
hallo, das ist ein Test
\paragraph{Nice ParagraphTitle ABC abc} So soll das sein.
%without lmodern: NICE PARAGRAPHTITLE ABC ABC
%with    lmodern: nice paragraphtitle abc abc

\end{document}
```